# How to use non-native mapbox plugin on Ionic 2?

Tags: javascript, cordova, ionic-framework, telerik

I'm trying to use a non-native Ionic 2 plugin called **Mapbox**. The reference site is [Telerik Mapbox](http://plugins.telerik.com/cordova/plugin/mapbox) and I make the following steps:

1. I install it via the **cordova plugin add ...**
2. On the page where I want to render the native map I declare at the top **declare var cordova: any;**
3. Finally call up the method to show the map

   ```
   if (typeof cordova !== 'undefined') {
     cordova.plugins.Mapbox.show(
     {...})
   }else{
     console.log("cordova is undefined");
   }
   ```

The error that returns is:

> Cannot read property 'show' of undefined

Ionic -> 3.5.2

Cordova -> 7.0.1

Why does not it recognize his method?

**EDIT**

I was able to install the mapbox plugin by downloading the repo and adding it as well `ionic cordova plugin add /path/to/my/plugin/my.plugin.folder.here/`.

Now the problem is always the same as described above. If instead I declare globally Mapbox `declare var Mapbox: any;` and then call it

```
if (typeof cordova !== 'undefined') {
  Mapbox.show(
    {...})
}else{
console.log("cordova is undefined");
}
```

the app crashed.

Comment: I am doing same but only Mapbox.show() code in platform ready. It is working fine. I have just tested and i am planning to work with corodva-plugin-mapbox (telerik plugin).

Answer (score 0):

Use `window.plugins.PLUGIN_NAMe` access non native/ corodva plugins.

```
import { Platform } from 'ionic-angular';

@Component({...})
export MyPage {
  constructor(public plt: Platform) {
    if (this.plt.is('cordova')) { 
        window.plugins.Mapbox.show(
        {...})
    }
  }
}
```

Comment: I added **(<any> window)** but still the show method does not recognize it @SwapnilPatwa

Comment: `console.log(window)` and check if Mapbox is there not in `Plugins`.

Comment: In the plugins folder there isn't. I only have the imagePicker object

Comment: @el_tuzcatore, in console log object? or projects plugin folder?

Comment: In the root of my project I have the plugins folder and there is the cordova-plugin-mapbox; But doing the **console.log(window)** returns so many things except mapboxes

Comment: then may be it was not properly installed.

Comment: try this `ionic cordova plugin add https://github.com/Telerik-Verified-Plugins/Mapbox --variable ACCESS_TOKEN=your_token`

Comment: I'm trying to reinstate it wih comand `cordova plugin add https://github.com/Telerik-Verified-Plugins/Mapbox --variable ACCESS_TOKEN=...` but I get the following error `Error: Failed to fetch plugin https://github.com/Telerik-Verified-Plugins/Mapbox via registry.
Probably this is either a connection problem, or plugin spec is incorrect.
Check your connection and plugin name/version/URL.
Failed to get absolute path to installed module
` Am I wrong something?

Comment: @el_tuzcatore use this command `ionic cordova plugin add cordova-plugin-mapbox --variable ACCESS_TOKEN=your.access.token`

Comment: It always returns the same mistake

Comment: run cmd with administrator or sudo(mac) `cordova plugin add cordova-plugin-mapbox --variable ACCESS_TOKEN=your.access.token`

Comment: Are you on Mac?

Comment: Ubuntu 16.04.2 LTS